# How can i populate this schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I want to use populate for this schema .
I tried some answers but they did not work

How can i use  $lookup  for populate  "user_id"

This is Search schema

```
const searchschema = new schema({
        
    job: { type: String, required: true, index: true },
        
    verify: { type: String, required: true, index: true },
        
    user_id: [{ type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", }]
        
})
    
module.exports = mongoose.model("Search", searchschema)
```

and this is user schema :

```
 const userschema = new schema({
    
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    
    name: { type: String, default: 'NoName' },
    
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    
    })

  module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userschema)
```

i am using aggregate so i want to use $lookup

this is what i tried :

```
{
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Searchs",
      "localField": "user_id",
      "foriegnField": "user_id",
      "as": "search"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please can you show the `.populate()` query that u have tried? And where is the `User` schema.

Comment: yes i change it right now @ambianBeing

Comment: @ambianBeing I changed it and i dont want use .populate() my friend

Comment: Assuming that lookup query is run on `User` model. Your local field should be `_id` and not `user_id`. Example: `UserModel.aggregate.lookup({ from: 'Searchs', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'user_id', as: 'search' });`

Comment: If that worked for you? I can post it as an answer and then u can consider accepting it.

Comment: @ambianBeing unfortunately it did not work but maybe problem is because of my code . yes post it i accept

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219461/discussion-between-sae-and-ambianbeing).